# passing arguments to functions in python using argv

Tags: python, python-2.7

Please find the below script

```
from sys import argv
script, contact_name, contact_no = argv

def operation()
    some code goes here
```

Since i run this script from command line, How do i pass contact_name and contact_no to operation function?
I am using python 2.7

Comment: Did you try your code? What didn't work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Allowing any no of arguments

```
from sys import argv

def operation(name, number, *args):
    print(name , number)

operation(*argv[1:])
```

Calling from command line:

```
python myscript.py Om 27
```

first and second argv ("Om" and 27 will pass to the name and number respectively)
additional argv(if any) will to *args tupple variable.

Comment: You shouldn't introduce the star syntax without explaining it. Explaining it well to someone new to Python is not easy.

Answer (score 10):

Command line arguments are passed as an array to the program, with the first being usually the program's location. So we skip `argv[0]` and move on to the other arguments.

This example doesn't include error checking.

```
from sys import argv

def operation(name, number):
    ...

contact_name = argv[1]
contact_no = argv[2]

operation(contact_name, contact_no)
```

Calling from command line:

```
python myscript.py John 5
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use `argparse` to write user-friendly command-line interfaces.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='You can add a description here')

parser.add_argument('-n', '--name', help='Your name', required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()

print args.name
```

To call the script use:

```
python script.py -n a_name
```